# Problem in RTL ( Git bash ) to convert css file to arabic direction

Tags: css, arabic, direction

I am facing a problem in the process of converting a CSS file to RTL, I am facing the problem on Git projects. The image below shows the problem.

Note: This tool is used to convert a CSS file from the default language (EN) to the Arabic language (Directions).[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqdV2.png)

Comment: can you include the CSS code that you're trying to convert

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.